# Approximate solution to the volume of an elliptic cylinder with unlike ellipses integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I am attempting to solve for the volume of an elliptic cylinder with two different size ellipses. This is not the same as an elliptic truncated cone volume. The ellipses are two completely different sizes with different ratios (a1/b1 not equal to a2/b2)

If we assume the volume can be approximated as a sum of discs we can use the equation v ≈ Σ πab * Δh

From my attached work I end up with the integration constant C. Is there anything that can be done to approximate this solution? I need to converge on an answer for a practical problem.

Any help would be appreciated.
[image: my attempt at the solution]

Comment: I don't think the concept of "elliptic cylinder" is well-defined.

Comment: It is a difficult idea to convey. If you imagine two different sizes ellipses on parallel planes that has the volume filled. I think you will get a better idea by looking at the picture I sketched.

Comment: Maybe you mean the *convex hull* of the two ellipses?

Comment: Do you, Kyle Smith?

Comment: You have evaluated a definite integral, so you should not have an integration constant. ... You have defined $a_1, b_1$ incorrectly because when $h=H$ you have got $a_1=A_1+A_2$ and similar for $b_1$.

Comment: Are the axis parallel ?

Answer (score 1):

We suppose that

- the ellipse axes are aligned with each other
- the axis lengths are linearly interpolated between the two ends

Then the solid's volume is
$$\pi h\int_0^1((1-t)a_1+ta_2)((1-t)b_1+tb_2)\,dt=\frac{\pi h(2a_1b_1+a_1b_2+a_2b_1+2a_2b_2)}6$$

Answer (score 0):

Leaving $\pi$ on the side,

$$\int_0^H(a+\frac hH\Delta a)(b+\frac hH\Delta b)\,dh=abH+(a\Delta b+b\Delta a)\frac H2+\Delta a\Delta b\frac H3.$$